# How to dynamically adjust iframe height of a Shindig Gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, opensocial, apache-shindig

I want to dynamically adjust the height of an iframe of a Shindig Gadget depending on content inside of it. After some research  I found out that it is required such iframe `src` to have `<!DOCTYPE ...>` declared to get the height of the content inside iframe using the following:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
```

But it is impossible to define a doctype inside `<![CDATA[` of a Shinding module. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the adjustHeight API in order to do this.  Calling the API without any arguments will adjust the iFrames height to fit it's contents.
http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/spec/trunk/Core-Gadget.xml#gadgets.window.adjustHeight

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Here is an working example [**click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nbTx/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj)
  {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
 }
</script>

<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have tried this method before, but it didn't work.